# Finding eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been doing the following exercise problem:

Let $T: R^3-> R^3$ be a linear transformation so that: 
[image]

Determine eigenvalues and eigenspace of T.

So, I determined that $0$ and $1/2$ are eigenvalues, with eigenvectors $(1,1,1)$ and $(0,2,0)$ respectively. But the unclear part is as follows: It says in the solutions, apart from this, that:

"Vector $(0,1,1)$ is not an eigenvector. But we see that $2*T([0,2,0]) = T([0,1,0])$, which means that: $2*[0,2,0]-[0,1,0]=[0,3,1]$ is in nullspace of T. 
Thus, eigenspace for eigenvalue 0 has the base $([0,1,0],[0,3,1])$. Eigenspace for eigenvalue 1/2 is $([0,2,0])$."

What I do not understand is: Why is $[0,3,1]$ an eigenvector for eigenvalue $0$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions are wonky, and have some computational errors. I think they meant the vector $(0, 3, -1)$ instead. Here's how it works (remembering $T$ is linear):
\begin{align*}
T\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} &= T\left( 2\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right) \\
&= 2T\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} - T\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= 2\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = 0\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

---

I know the question gave you two eigenvectors immediately, but beware of concluding from this that there aren't any others! In order to find *all* the eigenvectors, you may need to find some that aren't listed.

In this case, you were given the subtle clue that the linearly independent list $((1, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0), (0, 1, 1))$ mapped to a very linearly dependent list $((0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0))$. The first list is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, and in particular, spans all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The range of $T$ is the span of the second list, being the image of a spanning list. Notice how all three vectors are parallel, and so the range is $1$-dimensional. That is to say,
$$\operatorname{Rank}(T) = 1.$$
By the Rank-Nullity theorem,
$$\operatorname{Rank}(T) + \operatorname{Null}(T) = 3 \implies \operatorname{Null}(T) = 2.$$
In other words, there should be **two** linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to $0$. The other one can be found by finding a non-trivial linear combination such that
$$a_1 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + a_2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + a_3 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},$$
(e.g. $a_1 = 0$, $a_2 = 2$ and $a_3 = -1$, as used in the solutions), and then form the same combination of the vectors that mapped to $(0, 1, 0)$ and $(0, 2, 0)$, i.e.
$$a_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + a_2\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + a_3 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
By linearity, such a vector must map to $T(0, 0, 0) = (0, 0, 0)$.